# Background agent doesn't run when battery saver mode is on

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile, background-task, periodic-task, battery-saver

I'm using a PeriodicTask that works flawlessly, but it doesn't run if the battery saver mode is on, even though I've allowed the app to run in the background in this state via the Battery Saver app.

Any ideas what may be causing it from not running? I should add that I'm generating a new front and back live tile image using Telerik's LiveTileHelper control inside the background agent, and that a http request is made too (the app is a weather app). This is for a Silverlight Windows Phone 8 app.

Apologies for being quite general with the problem, but am assuming the explanation doesn't require me to share code.

Any insight will be much appreciated.

Bardi

Answer (score -1):

This is by design.

In battery saver mode the background agents do not run, including of course your background agent.

You can’t allow an app to run in the background in this state via the Battery Saver app.
Instead, you can forbid the app to run in the background even when the phone is in the normal state. But in the battery saver state **no** background agents are allowed regardless on the settings. The only thing that can be done with it — completely disable the battery saver state.

Comment: But that doesn't make any sense because there's an option in the Battery Saver app on Windows Phone 8.1 to "Allow this app to run in the background even when Battery Saver is on". The option to forbid the app to run in the background even when the phone is in a normal state is another separate toggle on the Battery Saver app called "Allow app to run in the background".