# Debugging a Windows Phone app when in battery saver mode

Tags: debugging, testing, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, battery-saver

Is there any way to do this?

If I have my phone plugged in, then even if I have the battery saver mode on, the fact it's plugged in takes precedence and so it's not running in battery saver mode.

Additionally, if I try debugging via any of the emulators, the emulators seem to run as if with 100% battery life and plugged in too.

Any guidance here is much appreciated. Hope I've missed something really obvious.

Thanks.

Bardi

Comment: try to write to logs...and save it in isolatedstorage. I know it's not a perfect solution...but it can help you somehow!

Comment: So there's definitely not a more convenient workaround? This thread was motivated by the problem I'm having described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027943/background-agent-doesnt-run-when-battery-saver-mode-is-on.

Comment: see this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx
"Battery Saver mode is an option that the user can enable on the device to indicate that battery life should be prioritized. If this mode is enabled, periodic agents may not run, even if the interval has elapsed."

Comment: Yep, I had seen that but if you've given permission to an app in the Battery Saver app to run in the background even when the battery saver mode is on, then surely the periodic agent should always run? Otherwise what would the point of this permission be?

Comment: you are right...but it seems that MS don't think like us :\

Answer (score 0):

I now this is an old question, but if you are using a WP8.0 project, you can use the [Simulation Dashboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206953(v=vs.105).aspx) to simulate Network, lock screen and reminders, but for battery simulation there is no actual way to do it. It's very creepy because the actual Visual Studio Emulator for Android allows to make simulations of the state of the battery.

[image]